# Ansible try different variables until the command was executed successfully

Tags: mysql, loops, ansible

I would like to backup MySQL by Ansible.The MySQL password will be encrypted by ansible vault. My question is our company has 5 different passwords for Mysql.
Is that possible to let Ansible try the password until mysqldump command was executed successfully (if password-2 works then stop trying password-3,4,5)

```
- name: Backup MySQL database in all VM
  hosts: mysql-group
  vars_files:
    - /my_ansible_vault_secret
  remote_user: ansible
  become: true

  tasks:
  - name: Run mysqldump in the VM
    ansible.builtin.shell:
      cmd: mysqldump -u root -p{{ password-1 }} --all-databases > mybackup.sql


#### Vault File ###

cat /my_ansible_vault_secret

password-1: password-1
password-2: password-2
password-3: password-3
password-4: password-4
password-5: password-5
```

I am very new to Ansible, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The real question here is not if you can, but if you should. And the obvious answer is no. This is a great way to lock yourself out of your MySQL accounts though.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ITnewbie, see additional details at [6.2.2 Connection-Control System](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/8.0/en/connection-control-variables.html).